# How to separate a user inputted string by the spaces n in Haskell IO

Tags: haskell, io

I want to ask the user for a sentence, and then return the sentence back but with the words on separate lines.

For example, if the user inputs `"hello I am tall"`, the computer returns:

```
hello,
I 
am
tall
```

I tried to start off a bit, but don't know of a function or something I can use to try and separate the sentence. My code so far:

```
 displayWords ::IO ()
 displayWords = do putStr "Please enter a line of text"
              x <- getLine
              mapM print x
```

I get the error:

> Couldn't match type ‘[()]’ with ‘()’

EDIT: One more side thing... using `mapM_ print (words x)` fixes what I want, but is there a way to print this without the quotation marks?

EDIT2: One more thing... Someone in the comments helped answer the previous edit, but if I change the format of this to

```
displayWords:: String -> IO Int()
displayWords s = do
     mapM_ putStrLn s
     return (length s)
```

I get the error

> Couldn't match type 'Char' With '[Char]'

How come `putStrLn` doesn't work here?

Comment: use `mapM_ print (words x)` instead

Comment: Is there a way to get rid of the quotation marks?

Comment: to remove the quotation marks, just `words $ filter (/='"') x`

Comment: I tried that but it doesn't seem to remove the quotations. Since the quotations aren't part of the actual string being input, it seems to be something added on when the program is printing out the output.

Comment: Yes, it is the output format of a String.

Comment: One question per post, please. Making fresh posts with fresh questions is not considered bad manners, don't worry; but spend a little time trying to solve it yourself first. (Half an hour doesn't seem like enough time to have made an attempt at solving each of the two followup questions yourself.)

Comment: `print` calls `show` to produce a string value, but you already have string values, which is why you are getting quotes. Use `putStrLn` instead of `print`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the `words` function to split the string into separate words.

Someone suggested `mapM_ print (words x)`, but since each word is a string, using `print` will wrap it in quote marks, which you don't want. So try

```
mapM_ putStrLn (words x)
```

Comment: Thanks, I have one more comment that is somewhat related. If I change the function from displayWords ::IO () to displayWords :: String -> IO Int, (because I want to print out how many words there are, and so I don't need to ask the user the sentence after starting the code), how come putStrLn doesnt work?

Answer (score 0):

Use `mapM_`.

- `mapM print` returns a list, the result of calling `print` for each element, but since `print` returns just `()` that is `[()]` not very meaningful.

  ```
  -- here, b = ()
  mapM :: Monad m => (a -> m b) -> [a] -> m [b]
  ```
- `mapM_ print` discards the result of each call:

  ```
  mapM_ :: Monad m => (a -> m b) -> [a] -> m ()
  ```

`displayWords` must be of type `IO ()`, and the type of a `do`-block is the type of its last statement, this is why `mapM` results in a type error.

Another way would be to ignore the result of a function like `mapM` by adding a statement that does nothing.

```
do putStr "..."
   x <- getLine
   mapM print x
   return ()
```

Comment: This gets rid of the error, but it doesnt help with my original problem of needing to seperate the words by spaces. This ends up printing every character in the string.

Comment: Explaining and fixing type errors is as far as I'm willing to go for homework questions.